# Animating div postion in fluid website

Tags: jquery, css, position, jquery-animate

I'm looking for a way to animate the repositioning of multiple divs in a fluid webpage, the div's do not have a fixed size so masonry script fails to do this.

Does anyone got a clue?

Comment: jQuery Masonry supposedly supports fluid layouts: http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/fluid.html. What do you mean by fluid?

Comment: Thats right, but masonry works with coloums and lines the divs accordingly i do not want to change the way the divs look i only want the animation

Comment: Could you elaborate a little about what you mean with repositioning divs?

Comment: I mean the repostioning after a window resize, so i have a couple of inline-block divs floating left and when i resize my browser some move to a second line. That is what i want to animate.

Comment: Seeing the code regarding the elements you want to animate would help. Thought I am almost certain that i dont know what would be needed to animate that.

Answer (score 1):

just use single column? http://masonry.desandro.com/demos/basic-single-column.html